# nginx proxy_pass 302 redirect everything not root to root

Tags: nginx

How can I get nginx to just redirect all URLs (except root, of course) to root, while proxying root?

We have an angular nodejs app that we're trying to take the built output from the generated dist folder and run nodejs's serve (`npx serve "dist/app"`) to run it in a deployed environment. The problem that we're having is that we're using angular routing in the app so that http://app/nested/url should just return from HTTP the root URL content and let the browser sort out the path and query. I'm trying to accomplish this with an nginx configuration.

So far, it isn't working; after a couple hours trying different solutions, everything I've tried from other SO / SF answers either just falls through to the proxy with concatenation of the path (we get a 404) <strike>or root itself fails</strike>.

Here's what I wish would work:

```
server {
    listen 880;
    listen [::]:880;

  location ^~ /([^/]+) {
    return 302 /;
  }

  location ^~ / {
    proxy_pass http://myserver:8081/;
  }
```

.. but calling http://myserver:880/login still just returns a 404, while http://server:880/ works fine through the proxy, it's as if the first location block wasn't there. I've also tried swapping the order of declaration, not sure if that matters but <strike>it just breaks it</strike>.

Testing/prototyping w/ ***nginx for Windows***, will be deploying on ***AWS Beanstalk*** (nodejs w/ proxy config).

**Sorry, I idiotically misdiagnosed some of my tests, where I thought it "just failed", in reality it was working, I just had all the dependencies (.js files, images, css files etc) not loading because they were caught by the catch-all. Duh.**

Comment: "it's as if the first location block wasn't there"   Perhaps you thought "^~"  was to be used with RE's.  It's not.  " If a carat and tilde modifier is present, and if this block is selected as the best non-regular expression match, regular expression matching will not take place."  See  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Comment: Regular expressions are introduced by `~` or `~*` modifier. The `^~` modifier starts a prefix match. I would simply use `location /` and `location = /`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
location = / {
  proxy_pass http://myserver:8081/;
}

location / {
  return 302 /;
}
```

Comment: this results in an infinite redirect loop

Comment: This doesn't. Your browser's cache or the backend may.